# How to make an API call with Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, api

So I'm practising trying to make API calls with Swift. The code is as below:

```
struct Example: Codable {
    let userID: String
    let ID: String
    let title: String
    let completed: String
}


func getJson(completion: @escaping (Example)-> ()) {
    let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, res, err in
            if let data = data {

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let json: Example = try? decoder.decode(Example.self, from: data) {
                    completion(json)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

getJson() { (json) in
    print(json.ID)
}
```

However, I am unable to print out anything when getJson is called.
The example API I used is found [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com).
The tutorial that I used to help me write the code is found [here](https://medium.com/@arteko/the-best-way-to-use-rest-apis-in-swift-95e10696c980).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your variable name and data type exactly as your API response.

```
struct Example: Codable {
    let userId: Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let completed: Bool
}

func getJson(completion: @escaping (Example)-> ()) {
    let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, res, err in
            if let data = data {
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let json: Example = try! decoder.decode(Example.self, from: data)
                    completion(json)
                }catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

getJson() { (json) in
    print(json.id)
}
```

You can also use CodingKey and can change your response during the init period.

```
struct Example: Codable {
    var userID: Int
    var ID: Int
    var title: String
    var completed: Bool
 
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "userId"
        case ID = "id"
        case title = "title"
        case completed = "completed"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        userID = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .userID)
        ID = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .ID)
        title = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        completed = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .completed)
        title = "Title: \(title)"
    }
}

func getJson(completion: @escaping (Example)-> ()) {
    let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, res, err in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json: Example = try JSONDecoder().decode(Example.self, from: data)
                    completion(json)
                }catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

getJson() { (json) in
    print("ID: \(json.ID) \(json.title)")
}
```

Comment: Can I ask how you would modify this to return array of Examples?

Comment: The answer is no longer valid. It can't find json.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ApiManager: NSObject {
     static func postApiRequest(url: String,parameters:[String: Any],completion: @escaping([String: Any])-> Void) {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        do{
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
                if let response = response {
                    let nsHTTPResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                    let statusCode = nsHTTPResponse.statusCode
                    print ("status code = \(statusCode)")
                }
                if let error = error {
                    print ("\(error)")
                }
                if let data = data {
                    do{
                        let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions())
                        print ("data = \(jsonResponse)")
                    }catch _ {
                        print ("OOps not good JSON formatted response")
                    }
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }catch _ {
            print ("Oops something happened buddy")
        }
        
    }
}
```